# Spring Data JPA - Creating custom query method generator

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In Spring Data JPA we can define a repository interface extending `Repository` and write a custom method.

If this method follows special syntax, Spring Data will generate the method body automatically.

For example (from the documentation):

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

Is there a way to customize the method generation code to introduce new keywords into the syntax?

For example:

```
Person findExactlyOneById(Long id);
```

This method would either return the entity or throw a custom exception.

I know I can customize specific repositories as well as the base repository and achieve the effect from the above example, but I'm specifically asking for the automatic method of body generation.

Is there an extension point designed in the framework? Or is the only option to change the source code?

Comment: What do you need that for? I cannot see the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can always use `CrudRepository.findById(Long id)` or `JpaRepository.getOne(Long id)`.
I would suggest inheriting from the `JpaRepository` class  because all types of repositories are included.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, is it? Rather a comment saying “You don’t need what you’re asking for.“ And I think you are right.

Comment: The findExactlyOneById was just an example and not something I need to solve.  I do use JpaRepository. This doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `nativeQuery = true` in the `@Query` annotation from a `Repository` class like this:

```
public static final String FIND_PROJECTS = "SELECT projectId, projectName FROM projects";

@Query(value = FIND_PROJECTS, nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findProjects();
```

It's probably worth looking at the Spring data [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) as well.

***Some more example*** 
***1.***

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```